# NSMutableArray is not replaced object?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to replace an array object in `NSMutableArray` obect.
I am getting `oldArray` from `_alertsArray` and changing its value and want to replace `oldArray` with `newArray` . but there is no effect!!

```
NSArray *oldArray = (NSArray *)[_alertsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldArray copyItems:YES];
[newArray replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:@"YES"];
[_alertsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row] withObject:newArray];
```

Comment: What are you checking after you do this?  "oldArray" will still contain the old, unmodified array.  (Incidentally, in this scenario there was no point in making a copy of "oldArray".)

Comment: If I am correct, your `_alertsArray` should be changed. Are you facing issue with that array?

Comment: @IndraKP, What was the issue with above code? It looked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [_alertsArray mutableCopy];
[newArray replaceObjectAtIndex:3 withObject:@"YES"];
_alertsArray = newArray;
```